# How to write prepared statements for SQLite in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite, prepared-statement

How to write prepared statements for SQLite in iPhone? Is it possible to do SQL Injection in iPhone apps that use sqlite db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that if you're starting to develop an iPhone app now you should probably use Core Data rather than coding directly to SQLite. Having said that, creating a prepared statement is simple and [well documented](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html):

```
sqlite3_stmt* statement_handle;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "select a,b from Table where c = ?", -1, &statement_handle, NULL);
```

And yes, it is possible to have SQL injection attacks in a badly coded application. Using prepared statements goes a long way to avoid it.

Comment: Core data is new to iPhone 3.0 right? SQLite would be safe bet, i believe, until Core Data penetrates well into the user base

Comment: My feeling is that most people who actually buy apps already have 3.0 or will upgrade shortly. Unfortunately there's very little solid data to work on.

Comment: Potentially there are things you can do more readily with SQLite than with Core Data

Comment: Absolutely. Core Data isn't the only option nor is it necessarily the best in all circumstances. But it's a good default.

Answer (score 0):

Along with Core Data, I'd also recommend looking at a higher level iPhone SQLite library such as: [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Comment: Is that "along with" or "as an alternative to"?  I've been working with SQLite myself, and need to start the switchover...

Comment: I was thinking Core Data **or** FMDB