# query select Sqlite Objective C iphone

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

well, I have problems with my queries,i dont know why!!  please help

i try to select an id from a table named moneda and I give the name like parameter,

**this is my method with my query :**

```
-(int)ConsultaIdMoneda:(NSString*) nombreMonedaParametro
{
    int idMonedaObtenido;
    NSLog(@" entre a consultar id de la moneda desde el app delegate");
    sqlite3 *database;

    const char *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database2" ofType:@"sqlite"] UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_open(path, &database) == SQLITE_OK)      
    {
        const char *sqlStatement =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select idMoneda from moneda Where nombre = %@",nombreMonedaParametro] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%s",sqlStatement);
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        NSInteger result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
        NSLog(@"%s",sqlStatement);
        if(result == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            idMonedaObtenido = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)] intValue];
        }
        else
        {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error . '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));            
        }
        sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);
    return idMonedaObtenido;        
}
```

**and this is the  error:**

```
2009-12-03 00:28:45.715 BCDTravel[1220:20b] *** Assertion failure in -[BCDTravelAppDelegate ConsultaIdMoneda:], /Users/Mely/Desktop/BCDTravel version 45/Bcd/Classes/BCDTravelAppDelegate.m:101
2009-12-03 00:28:45.717 BCDTravel[1220:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error haciendo el select. 'no such column: euros''
```

i think  the problem is  in this line  but i dont know how to slove  suggestions pleasee!!

```
const char *sqlStatement =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select idMoneda from moneda Where nombre = %@",nombreMonedaParametro] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are passing a character value you need to put quotes around the parameter in the SQL.

For example:

```
SELECT idMoneda
FROM   moneda
WHERE  nombre = '%@'
```

Otherwise, when the SQL is compiled, the value you pass in is itself treated as a column name (euros) instead of a candidate value of the `nombre` column.

Suggest you look into using prepared statements rather than assembling the string 'manually'.
See [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187154/how-to-write-prepared-statements-for-sqlite-in-iphone).

Comment: +1 for suggesting prepared statements. OP should look into the `sqlite3_bind_*` functions.

Comment: thanks :) that works! this is what i did:

  const char *sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select idMoneda from moneda Where nombre = '%@'",nombreMonedaParametro] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 0):

If you have special characters in select query, Use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead of `NSASCIIStringEncoding`.

```
NSString *s = @"select * from AddressGeocode where address like 'São Paulo, Brazil'";

const char *sqlStatement = [s cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```