# Insert string with unknown chars (i.e ‘, “, `, etc.)

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, insert, ios10, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am not too much good with database, but I can manage simple database operation. Currently I am facing one issue when insert data into table. Let me explain scenario.

In my app, I am searching places via `GoogleMapSDK` and then drop down list of places I am selecting one place. Then I want to add that place as a favourite and insert all data in database. Now the problem is `GoogleMapSDK` returns place name awkward something like : ''Sapna''SPa’’’’’’’.  And database query does not let me insert this data into database.

How can I insert data like this ?

I know is in above name if it contains one single quote or double quotes then can be managed with back slash, but how it can manage if you don’t know what data will be there ?

I want to store data as it is, without replacing or removing any char.

If anyone have solution, please share.

Comment: use prepared statements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187154/how-to-write-prepared-statements-for-sqlite-in-iphone

Comment: Thanks.... Let me try

Comment: Hi.... @Tschallacka can you please check my edited question ?

Comment: Please do not change your question so that existing answers become invalid. If you have a new question, ask a new question. (Or just add error handling to the prepare call.)

Comment: @CL. Please do not edit content. If I ask another question, then someone from you comment that do not ask multiple question for same topic and downcast question. I have already mentioned that I have tried solution which are posted, and after then it's not working.

Comment: These problems (and the likely solutions) are entirely different, and you even have different code.

Comment: Don't create a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290746/follow-on-question-vs-edit-to-original-when-to-use-which/290747#290747), it [will be rolled back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139215/discussion-between-vrawesome-and-cl).

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare your querys with variable placeholders instead of constructing the full query string yourself.

For example:

```
a) INSERT INTO yourtable (name) VALUES ('''Sapna''SPa’’’’’’’')

b) INSERT INTO yourtable (name) VALUES (?)
```

I'm not familiar with objective-c but usually you can run your querys safely in 3 steps:

1. write your query with placeholders and prepare it (like query b)
2. bind variables to placeholders
3. execute your prepared statement

Consult your sqlite driver's documentation for details.